# Which cable straps / staples for 12/2 BX/AC90

Tags: electrical

I am currently in lock down and can only do curbside  so I can not browse the packaging of the staples and cable straps in store. I'm having a hard time finding out what I should be using to secure my armored cable.

I am running 12/2 BX/AC90 cable, and I would like to run it along both wood, and concrete. I am looking for recommendations for wood staples and cable straps to   secure to concrete.

Located in Ontario, Canada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If memory serves, you want CI-2 2 hole cable straps, but you should call the hardware store before you order to confirm.  If you get the right size strap you can bend it around the cable and run a single screw through both holes.  10 by 1" pan head wood screws with #2 Robertson heads work well.  You can use them on wood and also in concrete with 1/4" plastic inserts.  For a nice surface mount look it's important to get the right size strap.